# Solve $\dot{S}(t)=S(t)A+A^TS(t)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I am faced with the matrix differential equation $\dot{S}(t)=S(t)A+A^TS(t)$ for which I have to find a solution. I remember I learned that the matrix differential equation $\dot{S}(t) = AS(t)$ has the solution $S = S(0)e^{At}$ but I am not sure this helps me here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach is as follows. Let $s(t) = \operatorname{vec}(S(t))$, where vec denotes the [vectorization operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)). Vectorizing both sides of the differential equation gives us
$$
\dot s(t) = (A^T \otimes I + I \otimes A^T) s(t),
$$
where $\otimes$ denotes a [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). From there, you could apply your solution. If you prefer, we could rewrite this in terms of the Kronecker sum (see the same page)
$$
\dot s(t) = (A^T \oplus A^T) s(t).
$$

---

On the other hand, here is a much fancier solution. Rearrange the equation to get
$$
\dot S(t) - S(t) A - A^TS(t) = 0 \implies\\
[e^{-tA^T}\dot S(t) e^{-tA} - A^Te^{-tA^T}S(t)e^{-tA} - e^{-tA^T}S(t) Ae^{tA}] = 0 \implies\\
\frac d{dt} [e^{-tA^T}S(t)e^{-tA}] = 0 \implies\\
e^{-tA^T}S(t)e^{-tA} = S(0) \implies\\
S(t) = e^{tA^T} S(0) e^{tA}.
$$
We could have arrived at this conclusion using the first method if we used the identity
$$
\exp(t A \oplus tB) = \exp(tA) \otimes \exp(tB).
$$

Comment: Really nice answer Ben +1

Comment: Thank you. This helped me! Are you missing a minus sign in the exponent of the last term of the second line for the "fancy method"?

Comment: @roi_saumon I am not: to get to the last line, I multiply both sides by $e^{tA^T}$ from the left and by $e^{tA}$ from the right

Comment: That final identity should have $tB$ instead of $B$ on the LHS.

Comment: @greg $tB$ or not-$t$ $B$, that is the question